# Find "Empty Frame" In an Array (simulation on LRU and OS)

Tags: arrays, c

I am having trouble coming up with a working helper function for my main, I believe the problem with my main program not working is because of this helper function.

its is supposed to loop through an array and see if there is an empty frame, i.e. an element that equals 1.

i have an array like this

```
int freeFrames[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1};
```

and the helper function like this

```
int findEmptyFrame(int freeFrames[])
{
int i, index;

for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("FreeFrame = %d\n",i);  // simple print statment
    if(freeFrames[i] == 1){
        index = i;
        return index;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

when I loop thru the array in my main Program it only ever reaches the 1st frame and returns it and doesn't ever cycle thru the next next element besides the first one

this is the section in my main where i am calling the function

```
else{
        x = findEmptyFrame(freeFrames);
        printf("X IS %d\n",x );
        if(x > 0){
            printf("IN IF BEFORE findEmptyFrame\n");
            PT[pageNumber].fNum = x;
            PT[pageNumber].vi = 0;
            frameNumber = PT[pageNumber].fNum;
            PA = (frameNumber << d) + dNum;
            fwrite(&PA,sizeof(unsigned long), 1, myWriteFile);
            printf("The Logical Address is at %lx and Translated Physical Addres is at %lx\n",LA, PA);
            lruCount[frameNumber] = clock;
            reverseMap[x] = pageNumber;
        }
```

and an example of what i am currently getting is something like this

```
IN IF BEFORE findEmptyFrame
The Logical Address is at b70 and Translated Physical Addres is at f0
FreeFrame = 1
X IS 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because in your for loop, if the freeFrame[i] is not equal to 1, the if condition fails. It therefore goes to the else part and returns -1. Therefore, you cannot return -1 within the for loop. You have to return it outside, like below:

```
int findEmptyFrame(int freeFrames[])
{
int i, index;

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("FreeFrame = %d\n",i);  // simple print statment
    if(freeFrames[i] == 1){
        freeFrames[i] = 0; //Change here
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

What this does is, if there is a 1 in the array, it returns the index. If not, the whole for loop ends and only then it returns -1.

Also, indexing in the for loop must start from 0.

If you want the first free frame to be marked used, you additionally have to do that before returning the index. Check the change in code.

Comment: It's better to start the `for loop` from `i=0` instead of `i=1`.  In the above code,  we are not testing the element at location `i=0`.

Comment: @twothreezarsix it is still stopping at the first element. It'll go to 0, then 1, but stop and return that. and isn't using the other 6 elements.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula  it is still stopping at the first element. It'll go to 0, then 1, but stop and return that. and isn't using the other 6 elements.

Comment: You want the index of the first frame that has value 1 right

Comment: @twothreezarsix yes, its supposed to go thru the array. if 0, means not empty. 1 means it is empty. after i use it, its supposed to go from 1 to 0, meaning its being used. but that is not what im getting.